# How to find translucent colour from the background colour and fused colour?

Tags: color, transparency, rgb

I need to find the rbg values and opacity of a colour that is translucent. I have the RGB values of the background colour and the fused colour.

[image: Image of colours with their values.]

As you can hopefully see in the image above, I'm looking for the RBG values and opacity of a reddish-orange colour. Is this possible?

Comment: I don't think this is answerable. To me it seems like different colors/opacities were used. Or some non-linear application of the opacity was used. I say that because all the r values of the "fused" colors are the same but the g and b differ

Comment: With a bit of humour I could guess that you are trying to get help with some math-homework. More seriously, please share how you obtain your values of the background and fused areas. Looks like you just built this image for this question. Is there a source? If it is confidential customer material, could you maybe share the original in super-cropped form just the section concerning your question? I believe some users could help you better if you give more detail. The clues might be in what you have but not see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been experimenting with this problem for a while now, and it can be solved, both mathematically, as well as experimentally, although the outcome in both situations is fuzzy on my end.

In both setups I have set the background or base layer as the colour to be calculated, while my overlay is your background color.
The blend mode used for this example is soft light, and following the formula given for soft light blend mode colour calculation here
[image: Blend mode soft light formula for Photoshop]
you can calculate your rgb values for each value (formula taken from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blend_modes#Soft_Light)), where a is the base layer value, and b is the overlay layer value. In your case, b is the unfused colour, a is unknown, the fused colour is the mathematical result of the formula, which is known.

Also, the overlay colour layer is set to soft light blend mode, just to clarify that again, because it is reversed compared to your example setup.

To calculate each value, you would express each value as divided by 255.
Look at the following example for calculating the a value for red of the base layer:

[image: the above formula’s lower formula with the value a/255 unknown, and b set to 248/255]
[Wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=2a%2F255*%281-208%2F255%29%2Bsqrt%28a%2F255%29*%282*208%2F255%20-%201%29%20%3D%20248%2F255)

Since b is ≥ 0.5 (b = 208/255), I have used the lower formula of the split formula.

This solved for a gives us
[image: solving for a]
or roundabout 245. This is the red value of the overlay.

Continuing for green and blue below.

Calculating for a’s green value gives us this

[image: same formula as above, but b set to 191/255]
[Wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=2a%2F255*%281-191%2F255%29%2Bsqrt%28a%2F255%29*%282*191%2F255%20-%201%29%20%3D%20191%2F255)

which solved for a gives us
[image: solving for a]
or roundabout 172. This is the green value of the overlay.

For the blue value, we need to use the upper formula as defined above, because 71/255 is < 0.5, which leads us to this:

[image: upper instructions of the soft light blend mode formula, with b set to 71/255]
[Wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=2*a%2F255*71%2F255%2B%28a%2F255%29%C2%B2*%281-2*71%2F255%29%20%3D%2079%2F255)

which solved for a gives us the final value of our overlay colour, blue as
[image: solving for a]
or roundabout 106.

And here it breaks down, because the calculated values for the overlay colour is noticeably off, although I can’t say where the fault lies: my calculated colour for the overlay is 245 172 106 or #f5ac6a, following the above formula.

On the other hand, through experimentation, I have found that the colour values of 248 174 87 or #f8ae57 are much closer to the example provided. I assume that further calculation, using the other two overlay & resulting colour pairs will provide more precision through averaging all three, for instance, but in theory calculating the one should be enough, provided it is one colour with one singular opacity of 1, like Zach Saucier has mentioned in the comments.